# Oscillating disk-pressure causes unnecessary eviction

Tags: kubernetes, resources

I have multiple pods on the same node sharing local storage. One of these pods writes a big file, which causes the node to experience disk-pressure. Because all pods share the same local volume they all use up this local disk space, even though the file was only written by one pod. `kubelet` comes in and evicts one of the pods. Shortly after a cleanup process will remove the big file, the disk pressure is gone and the pod can be scheduled again.

How do I avoid this? Is there a way to specify a `eviction-max-pod-grace-period` ([docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#soft-eviction-thresholds)) for disk-pressure?